# Skip or Filter records from a group if any row has null for an id

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to eliminate or filter or skip any group that has a null in any columns of that group.

Following is a sample dataset.

```
        courseId    personId    pointsWon       MobileTitle
        a1          alice       10              bluTest1
        a1          alice       null            bluTest9
        a1          batman      5               bluTest1
        a1          batman      5               bluTest9
        b2          robocop     1               test1
        b2          robocop     null            test2
        b2          madHatter   5               test1
        b2          madHatter   2               test2
        c3          batman      25              GOTHAM1
        c3          batman      25              GOTHAM2
        c3          superman    90              GOTHAM1
        c3          superman    null            GOTHAM2
```

From the above dataset, I want to sum pointsWon of every personId. If any pointsWon has a null, then that personId needs to be skipped or filtered from the courseId. Below is a sample dataset that I have been trying to fetch.

```
        courseId    personId    Total_pointsWon
        a1          batman          10
        b2          madHatter       7
        c3          batman          50
```

I have tried filtering based on Not Null, NVL etc, but am unable to filter or skip the user record completely from the courseId if any points inside that course is null for that user.

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Edit 1 :-
PN: The Datasets provided is just a sample made from a large dataset. I cannot hardcode any values in my query to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
with test(courseId, personId, pointsWon, MobileTitle) as (
 select 'a1','alice',       10      ,'bluTest1' from dual union all    
 select 'a1','alice',       null    ,'bluTest9' from dual union all
 select 'a1','batman',      5       ,'bluTest1' from dual union all
 select 'a1','batman',      5       ,'bluTest9' from dual union all
 select 'b2','robocop',     1       ,'test1'    from dual union all
 select 'b2','robocop',     null    ,'test2'    from dual union all
 select 'b2','madHatter',   5       ,'test1'    from dual union all
 select 'b2','madHatter',   2       ,'test2'    from dual union all
 select 'c3','batman',      25      ,'GOTHAM1'  from dual union all
 select 'c3','batman',      25      ,'GOTHAM2'  from dual union all
 select 'c3','superman',    90      ,'GOTHAM1'  from dual union all
 select 'c3','superman',    null    ,'GOTHAM2'  from dual 
)
select courseId, personId, sum(pointsWon)
from test
group by courseId, personId
having count(1) = count(pointsWon)
```

This simply makes the sum and, at the same time counts the rows (`count(1)`) and the rows where `pointsWon` is not null (`count(pointsWon)`) and then checks if the two values are equal

Comment: I cannot use hardcoded courseId values in the select query. This is because, the sample dataset is from a big dataset where it would just not be possible to hardcode the courseid's in the query. Your answer will not work for my scenario. 

I will add the clarification to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will accept it as an answer because it drove me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Aleksej, I was able to get what I required. Instead of using Union All with hardcoded values, I just needed to make sure that my internal query was optimized to provide me null values wherever my condition was not being met so that the outside select can effectively filter.

```
with test(courseId, personId, pointsWon, MobileTitle) as (
             select courseId, personId, pointsWon, MobileTitle
             from <dataset> where <conditions>
            )
            select courseId, personId, sum(pointsWon)
            from test
            group by courseId, personId
            having count(1) = count(pointsWon)
```